# Does the sum function compare one by one in order?

Tags: r

I'm sorry if this is too basic, but I was wondering if the sum function in R compares the first value of one vector to the first value of the other vector, then the second of the first to the second of the third, etc, or does it compare the first element to all the elements in the second vector, etc.

This is what I have tried :
`sum(databef$SD>dataaft$SD, na.rm=TRUE)`
It is supposed to count the number of times where the standard deviation `SD` of the database `databef` exceeded the standard deviation of the other database. But I do not understand how is the comparison made.

Comment: The sum function sums all the values in a vector, there are no comparisons?!

Comment: What did you try? See also: [ask]

Comment: Try this: `x <- 1:10; y <- 11:20; sum(x, y); x + y` and conclude by yourself

Comment: I mean : `sum(databef$SD>dataaft$SD, na.rm=TRUE)` @user2974951 @Jaap @ANG

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to achieve with `sum(databef$SD>dataaft$SD, na.rm=TRUE)`?

Comment: That code will sum only those values of databef$SD which are greater than dataaft$SD.

Comment: @ANG  sorry I have added some clarifications to my question. I want to count the number of times where the SD of databef was greater than the other. But does it comper row by row ? meaning, the first SD of databef with the first SD of dataaft, etc.. or the first SD of databef, with all the SDs of dataaft ?

Comment: Yes it compares row by row

Comment: @ANG perfect, thank you!

Comment: @Narjems YW! I put it as answer

Comment: Read about recycling, too. Try: `sum(1:2 == 1:3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it compares row by row. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(123)
databef <- data.frame(SD = sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE))
dataaft <- data.frame(SD = sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE))
sum(databef$SD > dataaft$SD, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 30 # this means 30 SD values in databef are greater than SD values in dataaft (row by row)
# A more intuitive way to do it would be:
table(databef$SD > dataaft$SD)
FALSE  TRUE 
   20    30
```

> Caution: Be aware that if databef and dataaft have not the same
>   length, recycling will occur!

```
databef <- data.frame(SD = sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE))
dataaft <- data.frame(SD = sample(1:100, 30, replace = TRUE)) # 30 obs instead of 50
sum(databef$SD > dataaft$SD, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 23 # works but you got a warning message
Warning message:
In databef$SD > dataaft$SD :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
# or
table(databef$SD > dataaft$SD)
FALSE  TRUE 
   27    23 
Warning message:
In databef$SD > dataaft$SD :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: "row by row" doesn't make sense, `dataaft$SD` is a numeric vector.

Comment: I just used "row by row" to allow OP to understand by using the same words than him/her. So you're right, it's all about recycling

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with `sum`. This is R's basic vectoring. When you pass any function a boolean phrase with vectors on both sides, it treats it as a set of comparisons, row for row, in the order of the vectors themselves. The result is a vector (the same length of the longer vector) of TRUE or FALSEs, which can then be summed (T=1, F=0).